# A triangle of forward differences in gawk

Tags: scripting, awk

I need a `gawk` script (not a one-liner, I need a function). Given a row of integers i.e.

```
0 2 4 1 9 5 1 1
```

the function should generate successive forward absolute differences, so:

```
0 2 4 1 9 5 1 1
 2 2 3 8 4 4 0
  0 1 5 4 0 4
   1 4 1 4 4
    3 3 3 0
     0 0 3
      0 3
       3
```

How can I do that using `gawk`?

Comment: So what have you tried so far and found a problem with? This looks suspiciously like homework to me...

Comment: I'm 41... and no kids! I would to differentiate (deltas) some files, in order to estimate variations

Comment: Fair enough. My bad for assuming. Calculating deltas for files is something that has already been beaten to death. This sounds like [an XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Maybe if you explain to us what your end goal is, you'll find somebody to point you to an already existent tool that does what you want.

Comment: Compute Nth. derivatives in absolute values

Comment: Oh, you mean differentiate in the *mathematical* sense of the word? Because your mention of "deltas" and "some files" threw me off. Does the solution have to be in `(g)awk`? Also, why do you need the output format to be pyramid-like?

Comment: Yes! in the mathematical sense!. Would be great a solution in awk/gawk. And pyramid-like. thanks!

Comment: You certainly can do it with gawk, but it's likely going to be easier in a slightly more powerful scripting language, perhaps python.

Comment: And do you really want the absolute value of the differences like that?

Comment: absolute values

Comment: @user49584 yet still, as Joseph R. mentioned, it is always better to come with something you have tried (no matter how much it failed) - it shows others that you are trying and not just crowd sourcing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is

```
#!/usr/local/bin/awk -f 

{       
        ns = 0
        while(NF > 0) {
                for(i = 0; i < ns; i++) printf " "
                print
                for(i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
                        $i = abs($i-$(i+1))
                }       
                NF--
                ns++
        }       
}       

function abs(x) { return x < 0 ? -x : x }
```